# Working with subfolders in custom view engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, viewengine

In a bid to keep my views organised within my new MVC 5 application, I've set up a folder structure as follows:

```
Views
|-- Account
|   |-- Partials
|       |-- EditUser.cshtml
|       |-- ListUsers.cshtml
|   |-- Home.cshtml
|
|-- Admin
    |-- Partials
        |-- AnotherPartialView.cshtml
```

Now, I'd like to implement a custom view engine for this so I don't have to keep specifying the full path to the `Partials` folder in my main view folders.

I've created a custom view engine like this:

```
public class CustomViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public CustomViewEngine()
        : base()
    {

        var viewLocations = new[] {  
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",  
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",  
            "~/Views/{1}/Partials/{0}.cshtml"

        };

        this.PartialViewLocationFormats = viewLocations;
        this.ViewLocationFormats = viewLocations;


    }
}
```

and registered it in `Application_Start()` within Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    /* snip */
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine());
}
```

**Edit:**

I call the partial views like this:

```
[HttpGet]
/// http://localhost/Account/ListUsers
/// View is located in ~/Views/Account/Partials/ListUsers.cshtml
public ActionResult ListUsers()
{
    /* populate model */

    return PartialView("ListUsers.cshtml", Model);
}
```

My thinking was that if I'm including the controller parameter `{1}` followed by the `Partials` folder within the view locations, this would stop me having to each `Partials` sub folder as a location. This would also mean I can just reference the view by name rather than its full path.

However, I'm still receiving an error that the partial view cannot be found in any of the search locations.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show an example of how you're trying to render a partial view? Because I've copied your code in the test project and it seems to be working fine for me. 
Also the view engine class you've shared here is called `CustomViewEngine` but you're adding `IridiumViewEngine` to engines. Is that your actual code or just a mistake while pasting?

Comment: @GwynBleidd Oops, yes the `IridiumViewEngine` was a mistake during copy/paste.. I've updated my post above with the way my partial views are being returned. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think specifying the `.chstml` extension is the problem, try returning the view without it:

```
return PartialView("ListUsers", Model);
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't pick up on that.. Feeling pretty foolish right now. :$ Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dave happens to all of us, no biggie :)