# ASP.NET How to register Custom View Engine using OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, owin

I'm trying to implement Custom View Engine that will let me specify additional View paths that looks like this:

```
public class CustomViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public CustomViewEngine()
    {
        ViewLocationFormats = new[]
        {
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };
        MasterLocationFormats = new[]
            {
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };
        PartialViewLocationFormats = new[]
            {
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
            "~/Views/Partials/Widgets/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Partials/Widgets/{0}.vbhtml"
        };

    }
}
```

There's a lot of source code how to use it in Global.asax.cs for example here: [Can I specify a custom location to "search for views" in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964/can-i-specify-a-custom-location-to-search-for-views-in-asp-net-mvc)
but there's no source that would show how to register this Engine when using OWIN. How to do it?

Comment: When referring to OWIN you are talking about Startup class, right? Are you in asp.net mvc 4 or 5?

Comment: MVC 5, yes startup class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**Startup.cs**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApplication2.Startup))]

namespace WebApplication2
{
   public class Startup
   {
      public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
      {
         ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
         ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine());
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can register this Engine in Application_Start()

like this :

ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine());

and you can look to this answer :
[Working with subfolders in custom view engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249464/working-with-subfolders-in-custom-view-engine)