# ASP.NET MVC controller return partial view that is not in Shared folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have this method inside my controller that calls this partial view:

```
return PartialView("_tinzProdListPageTemplate", tblStoreLocation);
```

That partial view is inside the `Shared` folder and the above code works fine and loads the view. But now I want to move `_tinzProdListPageTemplate` to another folder that is inside the `Shared` folder called `Templates` so that I can better organize my project.

I tried these but they don't work. It seems that only when calling straight from the default `Shared` folder, can you load a partial view from the controller. (I even tried adding `.cshtml` to the end as the extension on the examples above but did not work either)

```
return PartialView("Templates/_tinzProdListPageTemplate", tblStoreLocation);

return PartialView("Shared/Templates/_tinzProdListPageTemplate", tblStoreLocation);

return PartialView("~/Shared/Templates/_tinzProdListPageTemplate", tblStoreLocation);
```

So how do I return a `PartialView` that is not inside the `Shared` folder. Its inside a folder that is inside the `Shared` folder?

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 running on the .NET Framework.

This is the error I get:

> The partial view '_tinzProdListPageTemplate' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>
> ~/Views/Store/_tinzProdListPageTemplate.aspx
> ~/Views/Store/_tinzProdListPageTemplate.ascx
> ~/Views/Shared/_tinzProdListPageTemplate.aspx
> ~/Views/Shared/_tinzProdListPageTemplate.ascx
> ~/Views/Store/_tinzProdListPageTemplate.cshtml
> ~/Views/Store/_tinzProdListPageTemplate.vbhtml
> ~/Views/Shared/_tinzProdListPageTemplate.cshtml
> ~/Views/Shared/_tinzProdListPageTemplate.vbhtml

Comment: Can one of these help? For asp.net core https://stackoverflow.com/a/43473813/8715436 and for asp.net mvc based on .net framework something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7003742/8715436

Comment: What is the error message you're receiving?

Comment: @Charles I am receiving this error message:

The partial view '_tinzProdListPageTemplate' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Store/_tinzProdListPageTemplate.aspx
~/Views/Store/_tinzProdListPageTemplate.ascx
~/Views/Shared/_tinzProdListPageTemplate.aspx
~/Views/Shared/_tinzProdListPageTemplate.ascx
~/Views/Store/_tinzProdListPageTemplate.cshtml
~/Views/Store/_tinzProdListPageTemplate.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/_tinzProdListPageTemplate.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/_tinzProdListPageTemplate.vbhtml

Comment: @E.Shcherbo I took a look at the .net framework example but those seem to be showing how to do it from a view. I am adding this code in my controller.

Comment: I don't this this is specifically for getting them from a view. I would make a try (even your error is saying about view engine)

Comment: As per the error you shared, the viewengine is not able to identify the location in shared folder to look for partial views. The answer shared by E. Shcherbo solves that by adding that folder in the viewengine. You should give it a try

Comment: @E.Shcherbo haha! sorry I had like 10 tabs open on the browser and when I clicked on your link I thought I was looking at the one you sent me I was actually looking at the another tab on my browser. Thank you . Your post did solve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete view name would look like this

> "~/Areas/Public/Views/Home/Index.cshtml"

I think you only forgot to add the extension at the end.

Maybe you want a CustomViewEngine like here
[Working with subfolders in custom view engine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40249464/11808788)

If you register a custom view engine then you can set all the search locations like

```
ViewLocation, PartialViewLocation, MasterLocation
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that but still did not work. In my case I am calling it from inside a controller. In this particular case adding the extension gives me the same error.